# trigger click event programmatically on tree node with <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tree menu like shown below. I want to programmatically trigger a click event on a tree parent to expand the tree. Here "Dolor"-link is the tree parent node. (Also it has "+" sign prefixed).

How to trigger click event on the tree parent node?

```
<li class="parent item-8 closed">
    <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="item-9"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="item-10"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="item-11"><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
        <li class="item-12"><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
        <li class="item-13"><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Your rep is high-enough that you should know better to ask a question like this.  Sorry but what you have posted is not enough

Comment: Trigger the click event programmatically or display the submenu on click? Simply $(selector).click() in the firs case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin's tree node click event is working with the position of mouse pointer to restrict the click event on the expand/collapse icon only. So triggering click event programatically is not working. To enable this I've made a little change in plugin js file (`jquery.ntm.js`).

I've added `|| !e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')` to the `if` condition in `$('.' + options.parentClass + ' > a', this).click()` event. `e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')` returns `true` if the event is fired by user interarction, otherwise `false`.

The full click event will like following.

```
$('.' + options.parentClass + ' > a', this).click(function (e) {
    var posX = $(this).offset().left;
    var posY = $(this).offset().top;

    var clickX = e.pageX - posX;
    var clickY = e.pageY - posY;

    if (clickX <= options.spoilerButtonClickMaxX && clickX >= options.spoilerButtonClickMinX && clickY <= options.spoilerButtonClickMaxY && clickY >= options.spoilerButtonClickMinY || !e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
        var item = $(this).parent('li');
        var content = $(this).parent('li').children('ul');

        item.toggleClass(options.expandClass).toggleClass(options.collapseClass);

        if (options.slideEffect) {
            content.slideToggle();
        } else {
            content.toggle();
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Now `$('.parent > a').click();` will work perfectly.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/92hn56ap/2/)**

Comment: Great !! . Thanks Azim . My bounty will get awarded tomorrow . Nice explanation . Thanks Much.

Comment: Hi Azim . One more thing , i want to understand here is , why they blocked user click. Is this security reason?. One more thing , when i click any node the call never comes to the plugin code . Then how the logic is getting executed?

Comment: They do not block user click they just limit it to expand/collapse icon instead of whole `<a/>`. You can remove the `if` to enable click on whole part of `<a/>`. Call must be going to plugin code otherwise it should not work. @JavaUser

Answer (score 4):

You can `toggle()` `ul`  when you click on `.parent`

```js
$('li.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent item-8 closed"><a href="#">Dolor</a>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="item-9"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li class="item-10"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="item-11"><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
    <li class="item-12"><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
    <li class="item-13"><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And for nested `ul`s you can do this

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent item-8 closed"><a class="open" href="#"><strong>Open here</strong></a>
  <ul>
    <li class="item-9"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li class="item-10"><a class='open' href="#"><strong>Open here</strong></a>
      <ul>
        <li>lorem</li>
        <li>lorem</li>
        <li>lorem</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-11"><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
    <li class="item-12"><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
    <li class="item-13"><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: the same code is not selecting my tree in the page ...http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Collapsible-Tree-Menu-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-Nxeed-Tree-Menu/ ...i copied the code from this plug-in . Can you please help to make this "+" sign clickable programattically?

Comment: @JavaUser  You don't need plugin for this you can just do this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/622/

Comment: Thanks Nenad . My problem is , i want programmatically click on the tree node which is generated by the above plug-in(Nxeed Tree Menu) and it should expand. Can you please share the javascript for this?